# How to scale time-based aggregations with MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have a table of purchases with **nr_of_items** and **date_created** timestamps.

I'm trying to find a way to get the total **nr_of_items** purchased per month in a scalable way. The client uses this to plot a graph so it should be able to query at least 24 months. Currently I'm doing the regular Group By:

```
SELECT SUM(nr_of_items) FROM purchases
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(date_created,'UTC', "Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

But I see that this explains to

> Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort

...which implies it is not very scalable, assuming this table could potentially grow to thousands of rows per month.

I have looked into a materialised way of storing the totals per month by month_index, but clients may have different timezone's configured, so a month is not mappable to an absolute timestamp and materialising to all possible timezone's doesn't feel like a good idea (also TZ's do change sometimes).

Could this be solvable with MySQL? How? Or is there a specialised time-based DB I could use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) which is optimized for storing and analyzing time series data. It has a built-in support for all kinds of calendar aggregations:

```
SELECT date_format(time, "yyyy-MMM-dd", "Europe/Amsterdam"),
  SUM(value), COUNT(value)
FROM "purchases"
  WHERE datetime >= CURRENT_YEAR 
    AND datetime < CURRENT_MONTH
GROUP BY PERIOD(1 MONTH, "Europe/Amsterdam")
```

More details on:

- [GROUP BY PERIOD](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/#period) aggregations.
- [JDBC Driver](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-jdbc).

Disclosure: I work for Axibase.